# Vue global properties with composables / onScopeDispose() is called when there is no active effect scope to be associated with

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to write a composable that uses vue-query to fetch some data, it has a function that accepts string as argument and returns a piece of data based on that (it's translations).

When used as a normal composable in a component it's working well.

But I wanted to add this getter function as a global property with `vue.use` and that causes problems.

Here's a simple version of my code:

Composable:

```
export const useComposable= () => {
    const { data } = useQuery<TranslationsAPIResponse>({ options })

    const t = (key: string) => {
        return data[key];
    }

    return { t }
}
```

There are steps in between where I am typing the key object but I think it's irrelevant.

Main vue file:

```
vue
    .use({
        install(app) {
            app.config.globalProperties.$t = (key) => useComposable().t(key);
        },
    });
```

My main question is this even a possible pattern since I am using reactive objects in my composable?

When I use $t in component I get these errors:

*onScopeDispose() is called when there is no active effect scope to be associated with,

Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component.*

I am failing to understand why this code wouldn't work when it's working if I use the same composable directly in component.

Comment: could you show your component where you use `$t`?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev It's nothing special. For testing I only left two button components where I pass $t('key.something)' as a prop to show text inside button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Composable are meant for using in components. You are trying to use it outside a component. So component hooks cannot be executed like `onScopeDispose()` in your case.

So you could define your `$t` in the root app component, but better use some vue query's api to load your translations without a composable:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const self = getCurrentInstance();

self.root.appContext.app.config.globalProperties.$t = str => `<span style="background:red">${str}</span>`;

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-html="$t(msg)"></h1>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>
```

Comment: This is correct!
I have composable because I need to load all the translations in one api call and then cache that data and use it in app.

Comment: Why composables are meant to be used inside components? They should be defined in a way where they work both inside and outside components

Comment: @Roland If a composable contains a component hook i doubt it would work outside a component. If i'm wrong, please provide an example

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I am sorry to say that but you are wrong. A composable should be made in a way where we can use it both in components and outside of them so it's not true they are meant for what you said. If you want examples, almost all VueUse composables are coded in this way, to work both inside components and outside of them

Comment: @Roland `useQuery` in the OP's case doesn't work outside of an effect scope which usually belongs to a component. So this exact composable is for use in components only and I don't see any reason to add support of usage of a composable outside a component if there's no reason for that.